# How to sort a list firstly writing same elements, and then - by ascending order

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

I have a list of floats:

```
inputlist = [4.1, 8.2, 2.1, 8.1, 3.1]
```

I need it to be:

```
list_sorted = [8.1, 8.2, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1]
```

by firstly writing floats whose int(number) are the same (int(8.1) == int(8.2)), in ascending order, and then remaining elements, also in ascending order.

Another example:

```
inputlist = [9.3, 4.1, 4.2, 9.4, 8.2, 7.1]
list_sorted = [4.1, 4.2, 9.3, 9.4, 7.1, 8.2]
```

Comment: That's a pretty arbitrary order; have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: for what scenarios `sorted()` didn't work for you?

Comment: Not really. I have written a poker challenge program with the unverified assumption that I could sort the list this way. This is the only piece missing right now.

Comment: Sort the list ascending, then starting at the beginning move every element whose intvalue isn't equal to one of its neighbors to the back. That should give the sorting you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to make two passes: once to count the integer portions, then to sort:

```
from collections import Counter

integer_counts = Counter(int(num) for num in inputlist)
list_sorted = sorted(inputlist, key=lambda n: (integer_counts[int(n)] == 1, n))
```

The sort key produces a key with a boolean first (`False` for more than 1 value with the integer, `True` for just one), the actual value second. This groups those values with the integer portion occurring more than once first:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> inputlist = [4.1, 8.2, 2.1, 8.1, 3.1] 
>>> integer_counts = Counter(int(num) for num in inputlist)
>>> sorted(inputlist, key=lambda n: (integer_counts[int(n)] == 1, n))
[8.1, 8.2, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1]
>>> inputlist = [9.3, 4.1, 4.2, 9.4, 8.2, 7.1]
>>> integer_counts = Counter(int(num) for num in inputlist)
>>> sorted(inputlist, key=lambda n: (integer_counts[int(n)] == 1, n))
[4.1, 4.2, 9.3, 9.4, 7.1, 8.2]
```

The algorithmic complexity is still O(NlogN); the counting is a O(N) step, followed by a O(NlogN) sort, making the whole process O(NlogN).

Answer (score 1):

Would this be of any worth?

```
inputlist = [4.1, 8.2, 2.1, 8.1, 3.1]
def srt (lst):
    chkdict = {}
    for x in lst:
        y = int(x)
        if not y in chkdict: chkdict[y] = [x]
        else: chkdict[y].append(x)
    left = []; right = []
    for x in chkdict.values():
        if len(x)>1: left += x
        else: right += x
    left.sort(); right.sort()
    return left+right


>>> ["%.1f" % x for x in srt(inputlist)]
['8.1', '8.2', '2.1', '3.1', '4.1']
```

Note: I used string formating to force better look.

This isn't the most efficient way of doing it, but it is working fine for small or medium-size lists. It uses some of the same mechanism as in collections.Counter().